# Retrieve all rows with pagination efficiently in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pagination, offset, sql-limit

My application needs to retrieve all the rows from the Postgres table, however, due to unknown constraints I have to limit the number of the results returned from one query, say `limit l` (`l=100000`).

Therefore, a pagination with offset and limit comes to my mind as an immediate solution. However, [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html)  says:

> The rows skipped by an `OFFSET` clause still have to be computed inside
>   the server; therefore a large `OFFSET` might be inefficient.

Therefore if I request `pages_count * l` rows by paging `[1, l], [l+1, 2*l], ..., [(pages_count-1)*l+1, pages_count*l]`, in fact `(pages_count*l+1)*pages_count*l/2` which is `O(sqr(pages_count*l))` rows will be read.

```
for page_number := 0; page_number < pages_count; page_number++ {
 retrieve_and_store("select amount from transactions order by time offset $page_number limit 100000")
}
```

Or does Postgres cache the rows from the recent queries, or what would be an efficient way to retrieve all `page_count*l` rows?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results  (btw: why are you using an outdated manual?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is the manual that appears in Google search results.

Comment: @david: *A lot* appears in Google search results. Most of it is not what you actually want. Use the *current* manual unless you want to make this about the outdated Postgres 8.3?

Comment: As to your question: **it depends**. Is your table read only? If not, what are the write patterns and what are pagination criteria *exactly*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have only read-only access to the database. As per @a_horse_with_no_name's link, now I am using `fetch next` query.

Comment: If *anybody* (not just you) writes to the table concurrently, you may have to adapt your strategy.